Cisco ACS and AnyConnect authentication via RADIUS with MSChap-V2 not working
Authentication to AnyConnect works via RADIUS with PAP protocol, and I am trying to replace it with MSCHAP-V2, without success.
With PAP, ACS talks to the domain controller on port 1812, but by configuring MSCHAP-V2, ACS does not talk to the Radius server but instead refuses to log in with MSCHAP-V2 error E=691 R=0 C=<random code> V=3.
MSCHAP-V2 is enabled on Cisco ASA with password-management and authentication ms-chap-v2 commands in the tunnel group, and on ACS the protocol is enabled.


EDIT 1: user can successfully login with PAP_ASCII protocol, not with MS-CHAPv2.

Wrong password looks pretty obvious - have you verified that the user is AOK?

@Zac67 User is ok and can successfully login with PAP_ASCII protocol, canno with MSCHAPv2
